# Column Chooser in Fixed data table

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

Have someone implemented column chooser in fixed data table.
If not, can someone suggest me how to hide/show columns in fixed data table so that i can try implementing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can try this [Ant Design](http://ant.design/#/components/table) .

Comment: Completely agree with you !